# Login incorrect or forbidden by policy

Tags: boot, 18.04, recovery-mode

I am trying to boot the Ubuntu through recovery mode. When I select "Resume normal boot", I see the following window. Then, when I input the login and password, I get the red error: "Login incorrect or forbidden by policy". How can I resolve the problem?

How can I change it to GUI mode without using the login name?

[image]

Comment: What is the version and flavor of Ubuntu?

Comment: @Nmath it's 18.04

Comment: Reboot and don't choose Recovery Mode.

Comment: @user535733 The same problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To save my data, one solution that worked for me:

1. Create a bootable Ubuntu on a USB drive
2. Change the boot order in Bias to boot ubuntu from the USBdrive
3. Mount the specified drive to load my data
4. Finally, transfer all data to an external backup hard disc

And after saving my data, I reinstalled a new ubuntu version!